# Rails ckeditor extraplugin problems on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm developing a Rails 4.1 application. I use ckeditor 
(https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor), and I'm using some extraplugin 
(image2, which also uses widget), stored in app/assets/ckeditor/plugins 
directory. I used it with `f.cktext_area :extraPlugins => 'image2'`. It 
works well in development and also in production environment.

Now I decided to add one more extra plugin (syntaxhighlight), stored and 
used in the same way (stored in app/assets/ckeditor/plugins , called 
with `:extraPlugins => 'image2,syntaxhighlight'`). In development 
environment it works perfectly, but in production ckeditor cannot load 
syntaxhighlight plugin, because it try to load not the hashed version of it:

> uncaught exception: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name 
>   "syntaxhighlight" was not found at 
>   "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/syntaxhighlight/plugin.js"

I run "`rake assets:precompile`" many times, it generated the hashed 
version of plugins 
(/assets/ckeditor/plugins/syntaxhighlight/plugin-a9ce9661bf06ef29e7ac40baac50c044.js). 
But none of the working other (old) extraplugins do not have simple 
plugin.js in the public directory, and they work.

Any idea how to make work this new extra plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. To solve this, run:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

and after `assets:precompile` again.

Just to understand what happened: ckeditor gem generate a mapping file (override.js), and it maps the simple and the hashed version of js files. If you insert a new extraplugin, it will not regenerated with `assets:precompile`, you have to clear the cache to force it.